# Problem with rotation

Tags: iphone

Hey guys im having a bit of a problem with my iPhone app where i have told my viewcontrollers to disallow rotation (via shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:) and that works. However for some reason now my statusbar ontop of the window does animate.

The whole application is placed in a UINavigationViewController maybe thats usefull as extra information, so how do i solve this ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the supported orientations in your plist "Supported Interface Orientations", set it to the required orientations and you are done.